# Proving that $h$ is continuous at $0$ iff $f(0) = g(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $f,g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $0$. Define $h \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$
>  h(x) =
>  \begin{cases}
>   f(x) & x \leq 0, \\
>   g(x) & x > 0.
>  \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $h$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $f(0) = g(0)$.

The question wants me to prove that $h$ is continuous at $0$ iff $f(0) = g(0)$.
Since it is an iff statement, I suppose the proof will have two parts, one for the $f(x)$ and one for the $g(x)$ function.

However what I do not understand is why do I have to show that $f(0) = g(0)$ at $x = 0$ since $g(x)$ is not originally defined at $x = 0$, it is only defined for $x$ strictly bigger than $0$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: According to the statement of the problem, $g$ *is* defined at $0$.

Comment: "Since it is an iff statement, I suppose the proof will have two parts, ..." _ that much is true: two different directions of "if-then". But then you continue: "one for the $f(x)$ and one for the $g(x)$ function." Not at all; wherever do you get that idea.

Comment: When it says $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, it means that the domains of the functions are each _all of $\Bbb R$_. This means, in particular, that they're both defined at zero. (The second $\Bbb R$ in $“f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R”$ means that the range is a subset of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: What @AkivaWeinberger said. $g$ certainly is defined at $0$, you're told that (its domain is all of $\Bbb R$).

Comment: I think that no one really understands the OP's drama. He is confused because he sees a g(x)>0. To the OP: It means that h(x) is defined as the "combination" of the functions f and g: Imagine the plot of a function f defined on whole R and amputate the part of the right of the y-axis. Do the same with a function g but amputate the part on the left of the y-axis. Join those parts and you get h(x), noting that h(0)=f(0).

Comment: @BrianO I realised that what I've written is ridiculous. I meant the proof will be in two parts, first one is proving that assuming h is continuous at 0 then f(0)=g(0) while the second part is the opposite, assuming f(0)=g(0) to show that h is continuous at 0.

Comment: @user301198 Thanks for the clarification. I did get confused at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prove two conditional statements.

**($\Longrightarrow$)**: Suppose $h$ is continuous at $0$. Then its left and right limits at $0$ exist, and are both equal to its limit at $0$, which also exists. Thus 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0-} h(x) &= \lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) \\
&= f(0) \tag{$f$ continuous at $0$} \\
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0-} h(x) &= \lim_{x\to 0+} h(x) \tag{$h$ continuous at $0$} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0+} g(x) \\
&= g(0). \tag{$g$ continuous at $0$}
\end{align}$$

**($\Longleftarrow$)**: Suppose $f(0) = g(0)$. Both are continuous at $0$, so their one-sided limits at $0$ equal their value at $0$. We have to show that both one-sided limits of $h$ exist and are equal. Like so:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0-} h(x) &= \lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) \\
&= f(0) \\
&= g(0) \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0+} g(x) \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0+} h(x).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand what you are saying but I think that I have to use the definition of continuity with epsilon and delta rather than double-sided limits as we haven't covered them yet.

Comment: Then say so in your question. And/or replace the limits with epsilon-delta sentences (get rid of absolute values for the one-sided lims), and replace $=$ with $\iff$.

Answer (score 1):

First assume $h$ is continuous at $0$ and show $f(0) = g(0).$  In the second part of the proof, assume $f(0) = g(0)$ and show $h$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: OK, so you've converted *iff* into two conditionals. I'd say this isn't an answer.

Comment: Since the OP misunderstands what iff means, it might be helpful for him.

Comment: Well, that's a good point :) As it turns out (see his comments), he does (now) understand the nature of the problem and how to approach it — and perhaps that's thanks to your answer.

Comment: Yes, I thought that OP's misunderstanding of the iff was perhaps his primary stumbling block.